# Event test failing because of address's casing

Tags: hardhat, mocha, test, chai

I am trying to test if the event is emitted with the correct arguments however my tests are failing because of some casing issue.

[image: Failing test]

What is the best away to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is address checksum. Take a look at this resource to see if it helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71087892/assertionerror-address-changing-in-hardhat-tests